# My PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that deletes files in directory including files in subdirectories. I need it to  delete files in that directory only and not to delete files in subdirectories

Here is what I have:

```
    $DelFiles = get-childitem $DirectoryName -include $FileTemplate -recurse |where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).AddDays(-$days)}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `-recurse`:

```
$DelFiles = get-childitem $DirectoryName -include $FileTemplate | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).AddDays(-$days)}
```

Comment: I tried that and no files were deleted in directory and its subdirectories

Comment: Maybe there is something else in the script that needs to be also modified?

Comment: post the entire script please.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\WINDOWS\Script\CleanupTest.ps1 -DirectoryName \\nighthawkxa\f$\temp\Misz_Cleanup_Test\ -FileTemplate *.* -Days 0 -Jobname %%JOBNAME

Answer (score 0):

Powershell (v 2.0.-1.-1) has an interesting behavior

```
Get-ChildItem . -include *.txt
```

- will fail your expectation (will return zero matches)

```
Get-ChildItem .\* -include *.txt
```

- will produce proper-expected results. (will return all txt files in current dir)

It seem to be a part of it's design - see it's manual:

```
Get-Help Get-ChildItem -full
```

Perhaps you $DirectoryName has format like C:\111\, when for your datagrab you actually should provide something like C:\111\*

```
get-childitem C:\111\* -include *.txt
```

Hope that helps. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

remove recurse and add -file

if you want remove only files in directory and subdirectory

```
 get-childitem $DirectoryName -recurse -File -Filter $FileTemplate | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force
```

if you want remove only files in directory and not subdirectory

```
 get-childitem $DirectoryName -File -Filter $FileTemplate | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Tried that unsuccessfully

Comment: what have you in $FileTemplate  variable? Do you have files that matches the desired LastWriteTime?

Comment: file type .txt.

Comment: When I run this script with the command line that I provided above I get the followingWARNING: No files to delete:

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\WINDOWS\Script\CleanupTest.ps1 -DirectoryName \\nighthawkxa\f$\temp\Misz_Cleanup_Test\ -FileTemplate * .* -Days 0 -Jobname %%JOBNAME

Comment: i think you have an error in your filetemplate (you have an space caractere and my be your argument should be in quote). But you can use -filter  , i modify my code, look

Comment: No go either. Script works only with -recurse in presense. It deletes files in directory and its subdirectories as well. I just want it not to touch subdirectories

Comment: get-childitem $DirectoryName -File -Filter $FileTemplate | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force  work, i have tested. The problem is other

Comment: Esperento57, $DelFiles=get-childitem $DirectoryName -File -Filter $FileTemplate | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).AddDays(-$days)} | Remove-Item -Force did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you click on up arrow then ? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Esperento57, like I've mentioned before and files are getting deleted but only .txt files and the problem is that after modifying script there are no entries in the log on what files are getting deleted though. I understand that without seeing whole script, it hard to see where the problem is and what to do to fix it. So the bottom line is that files are getting deleted on the directory and not in its sub dirs. is there a way for me to show you the whole script? Let me know

Comment: hi, no problem, put the script and explain what you want

Comment: I can't, it has too many characters so I won't be able to fit it in :(

Comment: Hi Esperento57, I added a new question and pasted whole script into it.The new question is "This script deletes files in directory but would not specify the list of files it deleted"